# HTACCESS - restrict access to several domains / scripts

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, permissions

ok so, I have a central media directory. This is the private members files, I don't want this accessible directly.

There are 3 or 4 domains that access this member files directory.

How would I go about locking the directory down so only php scripts can access it from the web, and only from those 3 or 4 domains?

There's posts on locking down to a domain, and posts for locking down to php, but I can't find anything that locks down to php on a set of different domains.

Your help with this is appreciated, thanks for reading. :)

Comment: The posts on locking down to domains perhaps used notation like: `Order deny,allow NEWLINE Deny from all NEWLINE Allow from ip NEWLINE allow from ip` etc, just add more ip's after the first allow from.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the private members files, I don't want this accessible directly.

Don't put it under the web root directory.

> How would I go about locking the directory down so only php scripts can access it from the web, and only from those 3 or 4 domains?

There is no way to tell if a client was written using PHP or not.

Thanks to Virtual Hosting, there is no way to tell what domain was the origin of a request (as requests come from ip addresses and an ip address can have multiple host names).

Use password or public key authentication instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .domain1.com
allow from .domain2.com
</Limit>
```

Checkout more information Here http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/htaccess-block-domains-not-working-64831.html